# Show only configurable products on product listing page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-list

I want to show only Configurable products on listing page in magento 2.
I have used the code "
$_productCollection = clone $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
" in list.phtml file.

In frontend, i have applied pagination as well, to show 15 products first.
See https://prnt.sc/3_iXFgV-FoQC
But instead it shows only 6 products. https://prnt.sc/wMJUuEX72KNC
According to my understanding , magento is applying filter on the 15 products count, which contains both simple and configurable products, and then it applies filter in these 15 products , and returns only 6 configurable products.
Link http://discountedsunglasses.magento2e.com/women/sunglasses/aviator

note : This was working fine in magento 2.3. After i upgraded the site to magento 2.4 .It is not working properly.
Please help. Its urgent.

Comment: I would like to clarify some information with you. 1. What types of products does your site use (Eg: Simple, Configurable, Bundle, Group...)? 2. Do you want to show only Configurable products on the search result page too?

Comment: Yes, we are using Configurable products on entire site. We want to set simple product as "Catalog,search" but do not want to show then on listing page and search result page too.  We only want to show configurable products.

Comment: Could you tell me why you need to set simple products as “Catalog, Search”?

Comment: Thats my clients requirement

Comment: they ave set some url redirects which should work. You can check below 2 links. 1, https://www.discountedsunglasses.co.uk/arnette-sunglasses-dweet-d-3075-697-55-blue-rubber-dark-blue-blue-mirror (working link). 2. discountedsunglasses.magento2e.com/arnette-sunglasses-dweet-d-3075-697-55-blue-rubber-dark-blue-blue-mirror (not working link). It should not redirect to catalog search page

Comment: Thank you. Everything is clear now.

Comment: So is this possible? Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I’ll give it a try and reply to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140906/discussion-between-nicola-smith-and-tu-van).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModlueName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ConfigurableProducts
{
    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
    protected $productRepository;

    /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get products with filter.
     * 
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
     */
    public function getConfigurableProducts()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('type_id', 'configurable', 'eq')->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        return $products->getItems();
    }
}
```

call this function in listing page.

Comment: Are you overriding anything?  Please give complete steps in detail

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento 2.4 uses Elasticsearch,

- to show only configurable products on the product listing page (category page) you need to override [`elasticsearchCategoryCollection`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/etc/di.xml#L84) `virtualType` which overrides `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory`
- to show only configurable products on the search result page you need to override [`elasticsearchFulltextSearchCollection`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/etc/di.xml#L62) `virtualType` which overrides `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollectionFactory`

To achieve this, take the following steps:
**Assume** the Vendor name is `TuVan` and the module name is `Catalog`.

Step 1: Create registration.php:
File path: `app/code/TuVan/Catalog/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'TuVan_Catalog', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create module.xml:
File path: `app/code/TuVan/Catalog/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="TuVan_Catalog">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
            <module name="Magento_Elasticsearch"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create di.xml:
File path: `app/code/TuVan/Catalog/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="elasticsearchCategoryCollection" type="TuVan\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection"/>
    <virtualType name="elasticsearchFulltextSearchCollection" type="TuVan\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection"/>
</config>
```

Step 4: Create Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection class.
File path: `app/code/TuVan/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace TuVan\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext;

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\TotalRecordsResolverFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchCriteriaResolverFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplierFactory;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\ProductLimitationFactory;

/**
 *
 *
 * Override to show only configurable products on product listing page and search result page
 *
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private string $searchRequestName;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
     * @param mixed $catalogSearchData
     * @param mixed $requestBuilder
     * @param mixed $searchEngine
     * @param mixed $temporaryStorageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param string $searchRequestName
     * @param SearchResultFactory|null $searchResultFactory
     * @param ProductLimitationFactory|null $productLimitationFactory
     * @param MetadataPool|null $metadataPool
     * @param \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface|null $search
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder|null $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder|null $filterBuilder
     * @param SearchCriteriaResolverFactory|null $searchCriteriaResolverFactory
     * @param SearchResultApplierFactory|null $searchResultApplierFactory
     * @param TotalRecordsResolverFactory|null $totalRecordsResolverFactory
     * @param DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface|null $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        $catalogSearchData = null,
        $requestBuilder = null,
        $searchEngine = null,
        $temporaryStorageFactory = null,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        $searchRequestName = 'catalog_view_container',
        SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory = null,
        ProductLimitationFactory $productLimitationFactory = null,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool = null,
        \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface $search = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder = null,
        SearchCriteriaResolverFactory $searchCriteriaResolverFactory = null,
        SearchResultApplierFactory $searchResultApplierFactory = null,
        TotalRecordsResolverFactory $totalRecordsResolverFactory = null,
        DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $eavConfig,
            $resource,
            $eavEntityFactory,
            $resourceHelper,
            $universalFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $moduleManager,
            $catalogProductFlatState,
            $scopeConfig,
            $productOptionFactory,
            $catalogUrl,
            $localeDate,
            $customerSession,
            $dateTime,
            $groupManagement,
            $catalogSearchData,
            $requestBuilder,
            $searchEngine,
            $temporaryStorageFactory,
            $connection,
            $searchRequestName,
            $searchResultFactory,
            $productLimitationFactory,
            $metadataPool,
            $search,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $filterBuilder,
            $searchCriteriaResolverFactory,
            $searchResultApplierFactory,
            $totalRecordsResolverFactory,
            $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker
        );
        $this->searchRequestName = $searchRequestName;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * Override to show only configurable products on product listing page and search result page
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $applyCustomFilterToSearchRequests = ['catalog_view_container', 'quick_search_container'];
        if (in_array($this->searchRequestName, $applyCustomFilterToSearchRequests)) {
            $this->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', Configurable::TYPE_CODE);
        }

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

Step 5: Install the module: `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Step 6: Compile code: `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Step 7: Deploy static content: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

You are done.

Comment: Hi , this is not working for me. Have you added all the files and all the code?

Comment: Hi, Yes, which part is not working for you? I tested it before sharing it with you! My code allows your site able to show only configurable products on product listing page and catalog search result page.

Comment: If you apply my code and assume **1.** there are no modules overriding `elasticsearchCategoryCollection` and `elasticsearchFulltextSearchCollection` **2.** Or no modules overriding `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory` and `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollectionFactory ` **3.** Or you are not using other search extensions.