# How to fix str_replce Deprecated Functionality error in magento 2.4.4

Tags: php, magento2.4, deprecated

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the below error.
"Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated"

I am using magento 2.4.4 with php 8.1

Check full error message here https://prnt.sc/tT33R-c4w3SK.

Below is the line causing error.

```
fromDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-".$hseHelper->getNewYearBallFromDate())));
$toDate  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $hseHelper->getNewYearBallToDate())));
```

Comment: Please share you full error message here or screenshot of it.

Comment: please check my edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error indicates somewhere in your code passing **null** to the third parameter when calling a PHP function that is deprecated in PHP 8.1.

Assume you have below code:

```
return sprintf(
    $path,
    str_replace('methods_', '', $method)
);
```

The type of the third parameter should be changed to **string** if it is **null**. So the fixed code looks like the below:

```
return sprintf(
    $path,
    str_replace('methods_', '', $method ?? '')
);
```

The solution for your code:
Change `app/code/Velanapps/Hse/view/frontend/templates/new_year_ball.phtml`  `on line 39` to the following

```
$fromDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $hseHelper->getNewYearBallFromDate() ?? '')));
$toDate  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $hseHelper->getNewYearBallToDate() ?? '')));
```

Comment: please check my edited post

Comment: It's a typos when you add your code into your question, I've check and updated my answer, please give it a try. The error will gone

Comment: Can you please help me with this too https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361394/show-only-configurable-products-on-product-listing-page-in-magento-2/361401#361401

Comment: Which Magento version (specific version, eg 2.4.3-p3) you are using for that project?

Comment: its 2.4.4.......

Comment: I got it, I'll take a look but if it takes much time I'm not sure able to give you the solution soon.

Comment: Let me know if it takes time

Comment: @NicolaSmith Yes, sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

> **When you get this type of error then you should use this**

> **If string requires**

```
 $var ?? ''
```

> **If array requires**

```
 $var ?? []
```

> **If number require**

```
 $var ?? <addDefaultNumber>
```

> **If a Number type require and you have added a string type then (22 and '22' are different)**

```
intval($var)
```

> **str_replace(): Argument #3 ($subject) must be of type array|string, float given**

```
$float = 0.123;
$string = sprintf("%.2f", $float);
```

Comment: please check my edited post

Answer (score 0):

**OLD**

```
fromDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-".$hseHelper->getNewYearBallFromDate())));
$toDate  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $hseHelper->getNewYearBallToDate())));
```

**NEW**

```
fromDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-".$hseHelper->getNewYearBallFromDate() ?? '')));
$toDate  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $hseHelper->getNewYearBallToDate() ?? '')));
```

The `str_replace()` function in PHP 8.1 is deprecated for passing null to non-nullable internal function parameters. This means that if you use string casting, null will always be converted to an empty string.